# Issues with Automatic Reauthentication in Salesforce When Refresh Token Expires

Tags: authentication

Hello Salesforce Community,

I am currently facing an issue with automatic token refresh in my Salesforce organization and I'm hoping someone might be able to help.

Here's a brief overview of my setup: I have configured Named Credentials with Keycloak as the Auth Provider. This setup works well for initial authentication, and the access and refresh tokens are functioning correctly. However, I'm running into problems when the refresh token expires.

From what I understand, when the refresh token expires, Salesforce should automatically prompt me to reauthenticate. However, this is not happening, and I'm receiving 401 errors indicating that the refresh token is invalid, without an option to reauthenticate automatically.

As a temporary workaround, I've been manually revoking the access in the External Credential, which forces a new authentication and thereby obtains a new refresh token. However, this is not a sustainable solution as it disrupts the user experience and requires manual intervention.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: _From what I understand, when the refresh token expires, Salesforce should automatically prompt me to reauthenticate._ - how did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: According to Salesforce's OAuth documentation, Salesforce should use the refresh token to get a new access token when it expires. However, it's not clear what happens when the refresh token itself expires. In my case, I'm not being redirected for reauthentication, which I expected.